# Public function returning #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I've created public function and it's not working. I've tested the same function without var and it works.

Here is the code

```
Public Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range)
    Sum = 0
        
    DateBefore = Range("Bilan!B2")
    ColumnNumber = Range("Carto!BA2:FA2").Find(what:=DateBefore).Column
    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(2, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    Dim RangeBefore As Range
    Set RangeBefore = Range("Carto!" & ColumnLetter & "3:" & ColumnLetter & "10000")
    
    For Each rCell In RangeBefore
        If rCell.Interior.Color = CellColor.Interior.Color Then
            Sum = Sum + 1
        End If
    Next
        SumByColor = Sum
End Function
```

As I said, I tried without putting de CellColor as var, but directly inside the code and it worked.
The data is the same in var. That's why I don't understand why this code is not working and returning a #VALUE!.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Directly in Excel like this : =SumByColor(Bilan!A7)

Comment: @FaneDuru Versions since 2002 do accept `Find` (but not `FindNext`). I don't see how the code worked either way since it should be `Set RangeBefore = ...` Also, that function has to be made volatile to have any chance of being vaguely accurate (it's still horrible though).

Comment: @Rory Correct. Deleted my comment... It should be `Set RangeBefore = ...` and then check if the `Find` returned a cell.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've made so many changes before posting here.. But yes, I've edited and tried with the Set, and still, the error persists

Comment: What is in `Bilan!B2`?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav A date.`01/12/2020`

Comment: Have you tried defining your var as a date?  or putting a break point after it's set to see what it returns? `DateValue` for Bilan!B2 may help if date is in text in Bilan!B2

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of the function, then re-enter it in the cell and step through the code to see where it breaks. Most likely the `Find` is failing.

Comment: It broke at the `Find`. the date was correct, but I've changed to `DateBefore = Format(Range("Bilan!B2"), "dd/mm/yyyy")` and it now works. Thank you very much !